# Creating an empty dictionary with keys being tuples of variable dimension

Tags: python, dictionary

I am given a number of dimensions `m` and a number of indices in each dimension `n` (same in all dimensions). I would like to construct a dictionary which has all possible tuples of dimension `m`  with indices from `0` to `n` as keys, and `[]` as values. For example, if `m = 2` and `n = 3` I would get

```
{(0, 1): [], (1, 2): [], (0, 0): [], 
 (2, 1): [], (1, 1): [], (2, 0): [], 
 (2, 2): [], (1, 0): [], (0, 2): []}
```

I wonder how can I do this in a neat way, without the loops, and taking `m` as a variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.product` :

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> def comb(m,n):
...  return  {i:[] for i in product(range(n),repeat=m)}
... 
>>> comb(2,3)
{(0, 1): [], (1, 2): [], (0, 0): [], (2, 1): [], (1, 1): [], (2, 0): [], (2, 2): [], (1, 0): [], (0, 2): []}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dict constructor and [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
dict((x, []) for x in itertools.product(range(n), repeat=m))
```

Result:

```
In [4]: dict((x, []) for x in itertools.product(range(3), repeat=2))
Out[4]: 
{(0, 0): [],
 (0, 1): [],
 (0, 2): [],
 (1, 0): [],
 (1, 1): [],
 (1, 2): [],
 (2, 0): [],
 (2, 1): [],
 (2, 2): []}
```

EDIT: So I noticed I've arrived a minute late with an answer basically equal to @Kasra's, so I will add something to mine to not make it totally useless:

The dict comprehension used by him it's supported only from Python 2.7+, while the dict constructor I used also works on python 2.6 and probably before. On the other hand, using the dict comprehension is a little faster:

```
In [12]: %timeit dict((x, []) for x in itertools.product(range(10), repeat=5))
10 loops, best of 3: 35.7 ms per loop
In [13]: %timeit {i: [] for i in itertools.product(range(10), repeat=5)}
10 loops, best of 3: 31.8 ms per loop
```